# Sorting the grouped data as per group size in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two columns in my dataset, col1 and col2. I want group the data as per col1 and then sort the data as per the size of each group. That is, I want to display groups in ascending order of their size.

I have written the code for grouping and displaying the data as follows:

```
grouped_data = df.groupby('col1')
"""code for sorting comes here"""
for name,group in grouped_data:
          print (name)
          print (group)
```

Before displaying the data, I need to sort it as per group size, which I am not able to do.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

For Pandas 0.17+, use `sort_values`:

```
df.groupby('col1').size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

For pre-0.17, you can use `size().order()`:

```
df.groupby('col1').size().order(ascending=False)
```

Comment: I am doing df.groupby('A')['B'].mean(). Is there any way to get the means of the groups sorted using size? Thanks

Comment: @Neo Do you mean: df.groupby('A')['B'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False) ?

Comment: I think this will sort mean() values. I want to first sort groups(using their size) and then find mean of each of those groups.

Comment: @Neo I think this will do: df.groupby("A")['B'].agg(['size', 'mean']).sort_values(by='size', ascending=False)

Answer (score 16):

You can use python's [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: g = df.groupby('A')

In [13]: sorted(g,  # iterates pairs of (key, corresponding subDataFrame)
                key=lambda x: len(x[1]),  # sort by number of rows (len of subDataFrame)
                reverse=True)  # reverse the sort i.e. largest first
Out[13]: 
[(1,    A  B
     a  1  2
     b  1  4),
 (5,    A  B
     c  5  6)]
```

Note: as an iterator `g`, iterates over pairs of the key and the corresponding subframe:

```
In [14]: list(g)  # happens to be the same as the above...
Out[14]:
[(1,    A  B
     a  1  2
     b  1  4,
 (5,    A  B
     c  5  6)]
```

Comment: sorted function works good but it returns a list. Each element of the list is a pandas dataframe. So I try to access a column using the following code:

sorted_data = sorted (...)
print sorted_data[0]['col2']


But this doesn't work. How do I access each column of the dataframe in the sorted list?

Comment: It's a list of tuples, so you can iterate it with: `for name, group in sorted(..)`, then the column is `group['col2']`. Or you can do `sorted_data[0][1]['col2']`...

Comment: Oh Yes. I missed to to notice that it is a list of tuples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[5, 5], [9, 7], [1, 8], [1, 7], [7, 8],
                       [9, 5], [5, 6], [1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]],
                      columns=['A', 'B'])
```

> A   B
> 0   5   5
> 1   9   7
> 2   1   8
> 3   1   7
> 4   7   8
> 5   9   5
> 6   5   6
> 7   1   2
> 8   1   4
> 9   5   6

```
group = df.groupby('A')

count = group.size()

count  
A
```

> 1   4
> 5   3
> 7   1
> 9   2
> dtype: int64

```
grp_len = count[count.index.isin(count.nlargest(2).index)]

grp_len   
A
```

> 1   4
> 5   3
> dtype: int64